# Older PHP version fix

Tags: php

Trying to dynamically load a class:

```
    require_once(PATH_MODULES."/{$module}/{$module}_admin.php");        
    $admin_class = $module."Admin";     
    return $admin_class::get_admin($module);
```

Produces this error on older versions of PHP:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in 
/home/user/public_html/folder/path/admin/filename.php on line 91
```

How can I change this code to work for older versions of PHP?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491746/php-get-instance-of-static-class-by-string-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple:

```
    $admin_class = $module."Admin";

    $oAdmin = new $admin_class;

    return $oAdmin->get_admin($module);
```

Comment: What you do is not equivalent to what you do in your question. Here you call an object method, in your question you call a (static) class method.

Answer (score 5):

The problem as you probably expected, is that you cannot use dynamic class-names in PHP < 5.3. That's why the `::` is unexpected after the variable.

I don't see any way to go around this. You're not allowed to do this:

```
 $admin_class::get_admin($module);
```

If this part is always the same:

```
$admin_class = $module."Admin";     
return $admin_class::get_admin($module);
```

You could (and this is a hack!) add these strings to that module with the module name filled in ofcourse. Or make a separate file for that?

So for module `"yourModule"` you add to the `"/yourModule/yourModule_admin.php"` file these lines:

```
$admin_class = "yourModuleAdmin";     
return yourModuleAdmin::get_admin($module);
```

Or add a separate file that you call yourModule_admin.olderversions.php

Not too pretty, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP <5.3 you can use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func):

```
return call_user_func(array($admin_class, 'get_admin'), $module);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, go with a factory pattern similar to what you have done in your own answer.

One way would be

```
static class ModuleFactory
{
  static public function get($moduleName) {
    if(file_exists($moduleName)) {
      $module= new $moduleName;
      return $module;
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("Unkown module $moduleName");
    }
  }
}
```

Then you do

```
$fooBar = ModuleFactory::get("foobar");
```

I don't like string identifiers and try to avoid them when ever possible. So if you already knew all the modules you could do

```
static class ModuleFactory
{
  const FOO = "foo";
  const BAR = "bar";

  static public function get($moduleName) {
    if(file_exists($moduleName . '.php')) {
      $module= new $moduleName;
      return $module;
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("Unkown module $moduleName");
    }
  }
}
```

And you would then be able to do

```
$fooBar = ModuleFactory::get(ModuleFactory::FOO);
```

This would reduce the chance of getting the spelling wrong.